# Concatenate string and merging into one

Tags: php

I have concatenated two stings with PHP's `implode()` function.

```
Array (
  [0] => Work Order #4487199 Outgoing Email to Resident3 Test by System
  [1] => Work Order #4487199 Outgoing Email to Arigato by System
)
```

```php
$strTest = implode(',', $arrTest );
```

String is like this:

> Work Order #4487199 Outgoing Email to Resident3 Test by System,Work Order #4487199 Outgoing Email to Arigato by System

Now I want the output like:

> Work Order #4487199 Outgoing Email to 2 persons by System

Is there any way by using string functions ?

Comment: How's the string being generated? Can't you format it in the first place?

Comment: Is the username separate from the work order number and email recipient at any step? For example, are those strings generated from database records?

Comment: Instead of using `implode`, you can loop over the array and group elements together with the same `Work Order`.  Actually, how is the *array* generated?  If it's from a database, maybe you can group it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your main string "*Work Order #4487199 Outgoing Email to Resident3 Test by System*" like this, doesn't contain ','(comma) in between, you can use explode function, which is opposite to implode. It will provide the part of the string into array. You can explode on basis of ','

Comment: Did you mean that Instead of implode I should use explode ?

Comment: No.. You should input the concatenated string(which you get as result of implode function) into explode function. In your case, your concatenated string is $strTest.
Now you can write like:
$str_parts = explode( ',',  $strTest); Now, $str_parts is an array. You can loop through it and print the individual parts.

Comment: Is there any optimised way to get the outputed string .. ? by database way or php way..